# Integer not being interpreted

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code doesn't seem to understand the integer in the var.

```js
var btndelivery = $j('.delivery').parent("li");
var grandtotaltxt = $j(".gtman").text().replace("$", "");
var grandtotal = parseInt(grandtotaltxt);
alert(grandtotal);
$j(document).ready(function() {
  if ($j(grandtotal) > 60) {
    alert("plus grand");
    $j(btndelivery).show();
  } else {
    alert("plus petit");
    $j(btndelivery).hide();
  }
})
```

It always alerts `plus petit`.

Comment: Don't wrap grandtotal in jQuery.

Comment: What is the value of `grandtotaltxt`?

Comment: Change `$j(grandtotal)` to `+$j(grandtotal)` to covert the string to integer.

Comment: @AndreFeijo it's 700.00

Comment: You are getting the value of grandtotal before you check if the page is loaded. How does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable grandtotal was already parsed into an integer. It looks like you need to remove the jQuery wrapping to compare it to another integer. Also, if `$j(".gtman").text()` comes back undefined then the replace function will throw an error. It's probably good to wrap the code in an if statement.

```js
if ($j(".gtman").length) {
  var btndelivery = $j('.delivery').parent("li");
  var grandtotaltxt = $j(".gtman").text().replace("$", "");
  var grandtotal = parseInt(grandtotaltxt);
  alert(grandtotal);

  $j(document).ready(function() {
    if (grandtotal > 60) {
      alert("plus grand");
      $j(btndelivery).show();
    } else {
      alert("plus petit");
      $j(btndelivery).hide();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: You are getting the value of grand total before you check if the page is loaded. How does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use '+' sign infront of the variable you expect as integer.

like

```
var integerVal = +$('someSelector').text();
```

This makes integerVal variable an integer variable and you need not to put parseInt for it.
You can [refer this article](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/08/javascript-hacks-for-html-webpage.html) for more such JavaScript Tricks.